# Hovering/clicking/unclicking for highlighting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on an online English-Czech parallel text with two columns. There is a rough version [here](http://www.dinkypage.com/143262). Someone made the smart suggestion to have it where hovering the mouse over a paragraph highlights both that paragraph and its corresponding paragraph in the other language. This is especially useful because the texts do not have the exact same paragraphing. There is a smallish jsfiddle implementing this idea [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bAw6E/11/).

But I'd like to add a related feature. *Hover* over a paragraph and it highlights both it and its counterpart, *click* on a paragraph and both it and its counterpart *remain* highlighted, *click elsewhere* and the highlighting goes away.

Would this be easy to implement? I know almost nothing about javascript, and I'm just using another person's code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("label").hover(function() {
        $("label[class='" + $(this).attr("class") + "']").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        });
    });

    $("label").mouseleave(function() {
        $("label[class='" + $(this).attr("class") + "']").each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplified your code and added the click functionality: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/Urwem/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("label").mouseenter(function() {
        $label = $(this).attr("class");
        $('.'+$label).addClass("highlight");
    });
    $("label").mouseleave(function() {
        $label = $(this).attr("class");
        $('label[class="'+ $label +'"]').removeClass("highlight");
    });
    $("label").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $label = $(this).attr("class");
        $('label[class="'+ $label +'"]').addClass("highlight-click");
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
        $('label').removeClass("highlight-click");       
    });
});
```

ninja edit: Added correct code to answer.

Comment: @97847658 - I forgot to remove `console.log()`. Please make sure you remove that before going live!

Comment: I suggest using `.hover()` instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You have more code than is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is *close* to what you're after. [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) works as usual (notice I used [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). When you click, the highlight remains. To remove the highlight, simply click the paragraph again (this seems more user friendly and intuitive than "click anywhere"). It also allows for the selection of multiple paragraphs and is pretty clean code-wise.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Capture hover
    $("label").on("hover click", function(e) {
        var $label = $("label[class='" + $(this).attr("class") + "']");
        if(e.type == "click")
            $label.toggleClass("clicked");
        else
            $label.toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/FW4xK/).

Comment: I like your simple markup but you forgot to remove the clicked class when the user clicks off the label...

Comment: @user1090389, no, I didn't. Please read my answer and look at my fiddle :)

Comment: I see... I disagree I think the original is more user friendly. You're not giving instructions the user so if the user had to guess, they'd probably guess that clicking off removes the highlight.

Comment: @JamesHill, I'd vote you up if I could, but I can't (because I am you).

Answer (score 0):

Basic example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bAw6E/18/).

The code uses a variable to to indicate whether oon leaving pargraph (`mouseleave`) highlight should be removed. Default behaviour is to remove highlight and this is changed on click, only when click's target was `label`. Clicking anywhere removes highlight and so does hovering anther paragraph. Usability-wise you may want to alter this behaviour in order to make the highlight resulting from click more permanent and more difficult to turn off by accident.

```
var stayHighlighted = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is(':not(label)') ) {
            $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); 
            stayHighlihted = false;
        } else {
            stayHighlighted = true; 
        }
    });

    $("label").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $("label." + $(this).attr("class") ).addClass("highlight");
    });

    $("label").mouseleave(function() {
        if (!stayHighlighted) {
            $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        } else {
            stayHighlighted = false;
        }
    });
});​
```