# Automatic number incrementing for editing html?

Tags: html, autohotkey

I'm doing a parallel text with parallel paragraph highlighting. It's about halfway done, here: http://tinyurl.com/humecz2e

The problem is that it's very very tedious to manually edit the html so that each paragraph is flanked with incrementing numbers. For example:

```
<div class="indented numbered">
<label class="p2">
Those who have denied the reality of moral distinc&shy;tions, may be ranked among the disingenuous disputants; nor is it conceivable, that any human creature could ever seriously believe, that all characters and actions were alike entitled to the<span class="epagno"></span> affection and regard of everyone. The difference, which nature has placed between one man and another, is so wide, and this difference is still so much farther widened, by education, example, and habit, that, where the opposite extremes come at once under our apprehension, there is no scepticism so scrupulous, and scarce any assurance so determined, as absolutely to deny all distinction between them. Let a man&rsquo;s insensibility be ever so great, he must often be touched with the images of <strong>right</strong> and <strong>wrong</strong>; and let his prejudices be ever so obstinate, he must observe, that others are susceptible of like impressions. The only way, therefore, of converting an antagonist of this kind, is to leave him to himself. For, finding that nobody keeps up the controversy with him, it is probable he will, at last, of himself, from mere weariness, come over to the side of common sense and reason.
</label>
</div>

<div class="indented numberedlower"><div class="sbnumbered">
<label class="p3">
There has been a controversy started of late, much better worth examination, concerning the general foundation of <strong>morals</strong>; whether they be derived from <strong>reason</strong>, or from <strong>sentiment</strong>; whether we attain the knowledge of them by a chain of argument and induction, or by an immediate feeling and finer internal sense; whether, like all sound judgment of truth and falsehood, they should be the same to every rational intelligent being; or whether, like the perception of beauty and deformity, they be founded entirely on the particular fabric and constitution of the human species.
</label>
</div></div>
```

I'd like to do this automatically instead of manually, or perhaps some mix of automatic and manual. But I'm not sure how to do it. I have AutoHotKey, but I'm not sure if it's an ideal program to use, or even how to get it to increment numbers.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Counters)?

Comment: Perhaps explain why you need to have incrementing numbers in the classes, that is what you want to achieve, and we could think of a way to do that without having to have incrementing class names at all.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 No, I don't think so. The numbers need to be written into the html itself.

Comment: @MatthewLock Hi, I'm trying to get parallel paragraph highlighting, as per [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675870/hovering-clicking-unclicking-for-highlighting-text).

Comment: Why not just have a table structure with a column for each language, and each corresponding paragraph from each language in a row so that they all line up? Like so http://www.abbyy.com/adx/aspx/adxGetMedia.aspx?DocID=3175 you could format it nicely like so http://www.neilfreeman.com/publications_parallel_ex_zoom.shtml Once the paragraphs are in a table it would be fairly easy to highlight the table row using hover() in jQuery for example.

Comment: @MatthewLock The paragraphing for the two languages does not always correspond. See e.g. section 1, paragraph 10 of the English column. Does that fact change things?

Comment: Using the table you make them correspond. If there are less paragraphs in one language than the other then you show nothing in the other language for that row. Anyway that example you linked to probably had the text stored in a database and a server side script was used to generate the label numbers.

Comment: @MatthewLock I think there is a misunderstanding. Sometimes the Czech translation breaks an English paragraph into two separate paragraphs. Thus English paragraph 1.10 has been broken into Czech paragraphs 1.10 and 1.11. I'd like the highlighting to signal this fact, as it currently does. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: Can you put 2 paragraphs into the Czech row where there was only one paragraph on the English row? Essentially you want to use the HTML (tables, or divs etc) to group and represent the relationship between the paragraphs of each language so you don't have to bother numbering them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (var i in elements) {
        var elem = elements[i];
        elem.className += " p"+i;
    }
</script>
```

You might consider using unique IDs instead of unique classnames:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (var i in elements) {
        var elem = elements[i];
        elem.id = "p"+i;
    }
</script>
```

If you're just looking to style the labels differently, you could try using the [nth-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) CSS selector:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div label:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: red;
    }

    div label:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I know little about Javascript, but I'm wondering whether it can be used to change the html itself, and whether it's consistent with the fact that the two languages don't always correspond in their paragraphing. Thanks!

Comment: Javascript is evaluated by the browser when the the page is rendered. So the classes won't be written to your .html files, however when the page is loaded the browser will execute the Javascript and dynamically write in the class values for the elements specified.